Proving that outputs of isomorphism V --> W form a basis in W
Let $T$ be an isomorphism from vector space $V$ to $W$. Suppose $S=\left\{\vec{v}_1, \cdots, \vec{v}_n\right\}$ is a basis for $V$. Show that $\left\{T\left(\vec{v}_1\right), \cdots, T\left(\vec{v}_n\right)\right\}$ forms a basis for $W$.
I was going to simply prove that, since it is isomorphic, then the transformation matrix would be nxn, and that it implies that the columns form a basis for the output space. I was told I must use definitions of Linear Independence and Basis to prove it.

This is a standard exercise for most linear algebra books introducing linear transformations.
You will first need to prove that the set ${T(v_1), \dots, T(v_n)}$ spans $W$ and is also linearly independent.

Hint: If T is an isomorphism, it’s bijective. So for all $w \in W$, there exists a $v \in V$ such that $T(v) = w$.
Use the basis for $V$ to express $v$ as a linear transformation, so we have
$$T(v) = T(a_1v_1 + \dots + a_nv_n) = w$$
Then you can use the properties of $T$ being linear to show that the transformed basis spans $W$.
For linear independence, show the the transformed basis adding up to $0$ implies the coefficients are $0$:
In other words, prove
$$a_1T(v_1) + \dots + a_nT(v_n) = 0$$ implies $a_i=0$.
This result is nice because it shows that you can determine a linear transformation by seeing where the basis elements end up!
